# How do you convert an expression that works in the console into a format a driver can make use of?

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

I'm trying to convert the following expression for use in a driver expression:

```
1 if ( bpy.context.scene.frame_current == bpy.context.scene.frame_end ) else 0
```

So there's the "Give a man a fish" answer that expresses how to tell you're on the final frame of a render, and then there's the "Teach a man to fish" answer that more generally helps myself and everyone who follows learn how to make drivers work. But at this point I'll take whatever assistance a kind soul cares to render!

Comment: The code snippet works when pasted into the driver expression. Can you make your question clearer?

Comment: @Leander - My mistake: Python scripts were not permitted to run  -- I had forgotten that was an issue until I reopened the file and Blender prompted me to permit execution of Python scripts.  Thank you for helping. If you would like the credit points, suggest the step I forgot to take as your answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: Sure, thanks. I added an answer, feel free to expand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single line python expression as a driver, like an if-else statement.

```
1 if (bpy.context.scene.frame_current  == 1) else 0
```

The reason this fails, would be if python scripts have been disabled. You get this dialog after entering a python expression when python scripts are disabled. Click on "Allow Execution".

[image: auto run dialog]

If you dismissed the dialog, enable *Auto Run Python Scripts* in the User Preferences under *Save & Load*.

[image: settings]

Comment: `frame` in the driver namespace is `bpy.context.scene.frame_current` Will avoid the unexpected behaviour warning message... . The expression could be `1 if frame == 1 else 0` ore even `frame == 1` will  return 1 and 0 for True and False..  For others eg `context.scene.frame_end` it is recommend that variables are used to assist building the depsgraph.